# echo a variable and then grep to see if value exist in a file is not returning anything. Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: file, shell, unix, grep, pattern-matching

I'm trying to figure out how to determine if a variable contains a value from a file using grep, this is not returning anything, so I'm going to explain it.

I have my code that is this:

```
 MyFiles="MyFile-I-20160606_141_Employees.txt"
 DirFiles="/dev/fs/C/Users/salasfri/Desktop/MyFiles.txt"
 for OutFile in $(cat $DirFiles); do
    if [[ $( echo $MyFiles | grep -c $OutFile ) -gt 0 ]]; then
       print "The file $OutFile exist!!"
    fi
 done
```

and the file in /dev/fs/C/Users/salasfri/Desktop/MyFiles.txt contains the following values:

```
MyFile-I-*_141_Employees.txt
MyFile-I-*_141_Products.txt
MyFile-I-*_141_Deparments.txt
```

the idea is verify if the variable "MyFiles" is found in the MyFiles.txt file, as you can see is using the pattern "*" due that is a date, it will change.

that solutions is not returning any count of files, there's something that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your patterns are glob-style patterns, not regular expressions. The pattern `abc-*_X.txt` **will not match** the string `abc-1234_X.txt`.

You want to use a shell construct that does glob matching.

```ksh
MyFiles="MyFile-I-20160606_141_Employees.txt"

sed 's/\r$//' "/dev/fs/C/Users/salasfri/Desktop/MyFiles.txt" \
| while IFS= read -r Pattern; do
    if [[ $MyFiles == $Pattern ]]; then
        print "$MyFiles matches pattern $Pattern"
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: This is not for Bash, this is shell.

Comment: bash **is a shell**. Please specify which shell you are using, and on which OS. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shell/info

Comment: I mean, Korn Shell

Comment: Do you have the ksh93 version or is this an older machine?

Comment: it worked bro!!! I did some little different way, but it worked for me!! thanks bro!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the searchstring before searching.
An example with three teststrings:

```
for teststring in MyFile-I-20160606_141_Employees.txt MyFile-I-20160606_142_Employees.txt MyFile-I-20160606_141_Others.txt
do
   grepstr=$(sed 's/[0-9]\{8\}_/*_/' <<< "${teststring}")
   fgrep "${grepstr}" "${DirFiles}"
   found=$(fgrep "${grepstr}" "${DirFiles}")
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "${found} matches ${teststring}."
   fi
done
```

In your case you can make the code shorter with

```
   fgrep -q "$(sed 's/[0-9]\{8\}_/*_/' <<< "${MyFiles}")" $DirFiles &&
       echo "The file $(sed 's/[0-9]\{8\}_/*_/' <<< "${MyFiles}") exist!!"
```